# How do I run csc against a folder other than the current working directory?

Tags: c#, csc

Is there a way to run csc against a folder other than the current working directory, or is the best practice to copy .cs files to the current working directory and then run csc?

Comment: yes you can................

Comment: give the full path and do not forget to set your csc to environmental variable

Comment: have you tried simply specifying the path the the file instead of just filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you **can**  use full path names for your files **but** , IMO Easiest thing to do would be to open the visual studio cmd prompt (that way the correct version of csc.exe is accessible via path) and navigate to the location of your files and build from there. Or even better use [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd576348.aspx) if you need to provide complex project structure information  or go a step further and use a task builder like [Albacore Build](http://albacorebuild.net/))